# Trying to access data-attribute value of clicked option .

Tags: javascript

I have several 'page' options in select element, each option has values derived from database.

```
<select name="page_id" title="page id" class="form-control" id="page">
                                    @forelse($pages as $page)
                                        <option data-slug="{{$page->slug}}" {{($page->id==$c_page->id) ? 'selected' : ''}} value="{{$page->id}}">{{$page->title}}</option>
                                    @empty
                                        <option value=""> No Pages Found</option>
                                    @endforelse
                                </select>
```

I'm trying to get 'slug'value of 'clicked/chosen' option into javascript.

```
$(function () { /* DOM ready */
        $("#page").change(function () {
            alert($('option').data('slug'));
        });
    });
```

But this only returns the 'slug' value of 'page' option that is at the top. How can I get the value from other option elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `:selected` selector and use `this` the current element context (for which event handler is attached).

```
$("#page").change(function () {
    var slug = $('option:selected', this).data('slug');
});
```

As a runnable snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".page").change(function() {
    var slug = $('option:selected', this).data('slug');
    console.log('slug: ' + slug);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="page">
  <option data-slug="first option">first
  <option data-slug="second option">second
  <option data-slug="third option">third
</select>
<select class="page">
  <option data-slug="first option of second page">first
  <option data-slug="second option of second page">second
  <option data-slug="third option of second page">third
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick and saviour reply... since I'm learning.. What's second parameter 'this' for? :)

Comment: @Azima—the second parameter is unnecessary, it isn't used for anything in this case.

Comment: @RobG, Are you sure? second parameter is important if OP has multiple select element

Comment: Yes. `$(selector)` returns a jQuery object,  `data('slug')` returns the value of the `data-slug` attribute of the first returned element (if there is one). See the [*doco*](https://api.jquery.com/change/), ;-)